# Local website with xampp 1.5.5 and php 4.5 with apache on Windows. After some operation it doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I have a local website. It was written with php 4.5. I use xampp 1.5.5 on windows 10 (or w7). When I launch xampp control panel and Apache, the web site works fine, but after some operation it doesn't work and appears an error: Warning: (null)(): Invoke() failed: Eccezione. Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine Description: Errore non specificato. in C
C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/"namefolder...."/"namefile....".php on line 5

If I stop Apache from Xampp control panel and restart, it works. Every time I stop and restart Apache it works. But clearly I can't continuously stop and start.....

Comment: Please try to uninstall XAMPP and install new version of XAMPP.

Comment: This question should be asked on https://serverfault.com

Comment: I tried latest versions of xampp but they don’t support PHP 4.2 or 4.5 so the website doesn’t work because it was written with PHP 4.2.... or 4.5...